# Error con spring boot y paypal Access Token not found in cache

Tags: spring-boot, paypal

estoy desarrollando con spring boot un micro servicio para registrar pagos con paypal, me base en ejemplos de internet;

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

El metodo que realiza la primera llama es

```
public Payment cobroPaypal(SolicitarPagoPaypalDTO objSolicitud, String cancelUrl, String successUrl) throws PayPalRESTException {
Amount amount = new Amount();
amount.setCurrency(Constantes.MONEDA);

//amount.setTotal(String.format("%.2f", total));
amount.setTotal(objSolicitud.getValor().toString());


Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setDescription(objSolicitud.getNombreProducto());
transaction.setAmount(amount);

List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
transactions.add(transaction);

Payer payer = new Payer();
payer.setPaymentMethod(PaypalPaymentMethodEnum.paypal.toString());

Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setIntent(PaypalPaymentIntentEnum.sale.toString());
payment.setPayer(payer);
payment.setTransactions(transactions);
RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(cancelUrl);
redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(successUrl);
payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);




Payment retorna = payment.create(apiContext);

if(retorna != null ) {
    log.info("cobroPaypal.Respuesta de paypal retorna " + retorna.toString());
}else {
    log.error("cobroPaypal.Retorna respuesta nulo");
}


    return retorna;
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto al iniciar el micro funciona correctamente payerID y el paymentId, despues de un par de horas al volver a consumir el proceso me indica el siguiente error :

```
com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Response code: 401    Error response: {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access Token not found in cache"}
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:72)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:431)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:295)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
at com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.create(Payment.java:149)
at net.dualcorp.mscobrosbackend.paypal.service.PaypalService.cobroPaypal(PaypalService.java:72)
at net.dualcorp.mscobrosbackend.controlador.impl.PagoControladorImpl.solicitaPagoPaypal(PagoControladorImpl.java:137)
at net.dualcorp.mscobrosbackend.controlador.impl.PagoControladorImpl.registrarPagoPaypal(PagoControladorImpl.java:94)
at net.dualcorp.mscobrosbackend.controlador.impl.PagoControladorImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77feb59e.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
```

No retorna la url y no me deja continuar con las pruebas, tengo q reiniciar el micro servicio para que se vuelva a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciono, mi problema es que estaba usando un método deprecado del sdk de payapal

Por cada solicitud de pago se debe crear una nueva instancia del APIContext, de esta forma

APIContext context = new APIContext(clientId, clientSecret, "sandbox");